# invalidateLater Stopped in R shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shiny app, and there is a plot which is getting updated each 10 seconds. The app works perfectly and it is getting updated. However, after some number of updating, namely around 30 times, it stops with no reason.

Using for chart update:

```
invalidateLater
```

Would you please let me know what I should do?

```
library("shiny")
library("shinythemes")
library("ggplot2")

## generating the time of the system
t <- Sys.time()
n <- 101 # some time lage
df <- data.frame(c(1:1000), runif(1000, 0, 1) )  # in addition, df is just a dataframe in the memory

shinyUI(

  tabPanel("Home", plotOutput(outputId = "plot0") )

)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot0 <- renderPlot({  # Signal realtime View
  invalidateLater(500, session) # updating the plot each 500 miliseconds

  n <- as.integer(Sys.time() - t) + n # updating the new elements which should be visualized
  ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = df[((n-100) :n), 1], y = df[((n-100) :n) , 2]     ), colour = "blue") +      
  xlab("Time [s]") + ylab("Channel") # normal ggplot :-)

  })
})
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code please

Comment: Thanks for replying :-) df is a dataset which is uploaded in the memory already.

Comment: the code is also updated :-) @PorkChop

Comment: a simple numeric dataframe
`df <- data.frame(c(1:1000), c(1:1000) )`

Comment: if you are running the code, you will see it will work till 150s and after that it stops :-|

Comment: Perfect! It works solidly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time difference calculation doesnt take into account where the difference is in seconds, minutes or hours, so after 60 seconds the difference will be 1.

Try something like this:

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library("ggplot2")
t <- Sys.time()
n <- 101 # some evaluation
df <- data.frame(c(1:1000), c(1:1000) )

ui<-  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Distribution analysis"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot0"))
))

server<- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  mydata <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(300, session) # updating the plot each 300 miliseconds
    n <- as.integer(difftime(Sys.time(),t, units = "secs")) + n # updating the new elements which should be visualized
    df[((n-100) :n),]
  })

  output$plot0 <- renderPlot({  # Signal realtime View
    ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = mydata()[,1], y = mydata()[,2]), colour = "blue") +      
      xlab("Time [s]") + ylab("Channel") # normal ggplot :-)
  })
})  
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! bad mistake! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @AliShetabBoushehri, Ideally you want only `JS` code updating new values and not rendering it all the time. Look into other options such as `dygraphs` and `highcharter`